# Laravel 5, page can't be reached takes too long to respond

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have Laravel application running on localhost, I tried to run it on my smartphone so i connect my smartphone and my computer on the same network and in my phone at URL i type the IP address of my computer instead of localhost 
192.168.43.224:8000. But the page won't come,  it says page can't be reached,  192.168.43.224 takes too long to respond..  Help please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the page takes so long time, but that it's not reachable!
If you're not bound to using Apache or nginx for some special reason and this is for development purposes only, you could serve the application using artisan serve command.
It's by far the easiest thing to setup, and will only require you to run one command in the Laravel application directory:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

The default port it will be listening to will be 8000 to avoid any conflicts, so you can now access the application from your phone via the IP address of your computer:

```
http://192.168.1.101:8000
```

If you want to listen to another port (for example the default HTTP port of 80) you can pass that as a parameter, just make sure no other server is running on that port. So if you run this instead:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

You can now access your application with just the IP address:

```
http://192.168.1.101
```

Comment: Thanx, it works. I just wrote Php artisan serve --host 192.168.43.224